# Save a value at an RSI cross and use it as another cross value "later"

Tags: variables, scope, pine-script

Brand new to PineScript, but a long-time programmer. I'm trying to make a strategy/indicator that essentially marks the price at an RSI cross and calculates a new value that is a certain % down from the price at that initial cross and then checks for a cross under that new value.

I have included a visual example for added clarity (hopefully).

In terms of variables and scope, I'm finding that Pine is very different from Python and C which I am most accustomed to. So I am asking this just hoping to get very basic guidance on where to start with this.

Mainly just how to hold that crossed RSI price variable and use it in a cross-check later on.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVufb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of a certain point with `valuewhen()` function, `valuewhen(condition, source, occurrence) → series[float]`
The formula is straight forward, you tell the condition (rsi cross in your case), which value to get (the close candle) and the occurence (0, to get it every time the condition is met)

```
//@version=4
study(title="My Script", overlay = true)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
// plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
upper = 70
lower = 30
// fill(upper, lower, color=#9915FF, transp=90)

val_dn = valuewhen(crossunder(rsi, lower), close, 0)
plot(val_dn, color = color.yellow)
```

As you can see in the bellow image (I plotted the `valuewhen()` to see how it's woriking), when the RSI cross under occurs, will give you the value of the closed candle.

From here I think you can do the n% down part. :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about valuewhen()!